# MD5 para proteger senha fica mudando a hash

Tags: php

Estou com um código para proteger a senha do banco de dados bem básico. Porem para fazer o login sempre estou utilizando o seguinte:

```
$email = $post['email'];
$senha = md5($post['senha']);
return $this->model->Query('SELECT * FROM 
usuario WHERE email = ? AND senha = ? AND deletado = ? 
ORDER BY id ASC', array($email, $senha, 0));
```

Só que o md5 começou a apresentar um comportamento que não havia observado antes, ele esta mudando a hash constantemente no login, coisa que nunca havia acontecido antes, talvez por falta de observação.

Como devo fazer para que a hash do banco de dados bata de acordo com a hash do login ?

Att.

Comment: O hash da mesma senha varia em chamadas diferentes do código? Tem certeza que é a mesma senha?

Comment: Proteger senha com MD5 é como proteger uma baleia com um barco de pesca japonês.

Comment: Anderson, sim retorna sempre a mesma senha 'admin' e com hash diferente.
Renan eu sei que é fraco, tem uns esquema por trás que estou montando.